# How to quickly clear a text input?

Tags: functionality

Is it possible to quickly clear the contents of a text input? I cannot find a "select all text" option and selecting a word and then dragging the text marker doesn't work very well in a single line text box with overflowing text.

Example usage: Clearing the search input on Google.com in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an option that I am aware of that will select all text at once for you. But instead of manually selecting the text and deleting, you can position the cursor at the end and then hold down the backspace button. It will start deleting characters more slowly but after a second or so, it will start deleting faster and whole words at a time. This will speed things up considerably.

Of course this isn't a perfect solution for very large blocks of text. Unfortunately I don't believe that there are any better options at his time.

Comment: It takes a while for it to start deleting things a word at a time, but the main problem with this is that you don't seem to be able to position the cursor at the end.

Comment: @row1 You can. Just tap and hold to get control of the cursor and then drag it past the right edge of the text box. It should scroll the input all the way to the end and let you place it there.

Comment: Sorry I should rephrase that to that you cannot easily and quickly move to the end of the box. Your answer seems to be the only solution.

Comment: I usually tap a word then drag the cursor to the edges.

Comment: @row1 I agree it is a bit clumsy but it's all we have right now. What's worse is trying to block delete an entire paragraph in a web form. I think this is a limitation of touch-based UIs in general, though. This is where full-size keyboards are superior.